# Remove string after character in where statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I created the following query to remove the last digits after the dot of a project number: 1234.**0001**

```
     SELECT
     CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', project) > 0 THEN
        LEFT(project, CHARINDEX('.', project)-1) ELSE
        project END
    FROM projects_table
WHERE Project between 1000 AND 2000
```

Because I need the original project number as result the case should not included in the `select` part, but in the `where` part of the query.

```
    SELECT
        Project
    FROM projects_table
    WHERE project = CASE 
              WHEN CHARINDEX('.', project) > 0 AND Project BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
                  THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END
```

**Update**
The project column is a nvarchar(20) column which gives the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '271636.001' to
>   data type int.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I guess that's because there is no project with name equal to "1".

Comment: Clarify  what you are asking.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Updated the question

Comment: Update your question: which part of multipart project name/number you want to filter, do you want to filter it as numbers or strings, add sample source dataset and desired result for filter given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause is incorrect. The evaluation is never `TRUE` as 1 is most likely never equal to the result of `LEFT(project, CHARINDEX('.', project)-1)`.

You should use:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE 
              WHEN CHARINDEX('.', project) > 0 AND CAST(Project AS NUMERIC(18,5)) BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
                  THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END
```

The simplified version of this condition (and you can replace it with) is:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('.', project) > 0
    AND CAST(Project AS NUMERIC(18,5)) BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

Comment: `where CHARINDEX('.', project) > 0` ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes, that would be the simplified version of the condition, but I wanted to explain why his `CASE` is not working as he is expecting.

Comment: @CitizenDB you need to update your question totally. Which part of multipart name you want to filter, you want to filter it as numbers or strings, sample dataset and desired result.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Thanks for the updated answer. I now get: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '4352.001' to data type int.

Comment: @CitizenDB So, I assume that your `Project` column is not an integer, but a string. I've updated my answer, try now.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu true. it is a nvarchar(20)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT
    Project
FROM projects_table
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', project) > 0 THEN
    1 ELSE
    project END
```